# ImageField url attribute

Tags: django

**Django 3.0.6**

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{}" width="150" height="150" alt={} />'.format(self.image_300_webp_1.url, 
                                                                                   self.alt))
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Test:**

```
>>> from image.models import Image
>>> i = Image.objects.first()
>>> i.image_tag()
'<img src="/media/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/pcask/media/image/1/1_300_1x.webp" width="150" height="150" alt=asdf />'
```

**The problem:**
Real path is /media/image/1/1_300_1x.webp. Could you tell me why it is: media + absolute path to the image? And how to get the correct path?

Comment: What is the value of `i.image_300_webp_1.url`?

Comment: It is: '/media/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/pcask/media/image/1/1_300_1x.webp'

Answer (score 0):

add Media url to urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

please see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)!

Comment: How can it help? I test in the shell. Secondly, it had already been added before the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to was written wrongly. Wrong variant is commented.

```
def _get_upload_to(_, filename):
    # dir_to_create = '{}/image/{}/'.format(MEDIA_ROOT, extrapolated_image_id)
    dir_to_create = 'image/{}/'.format(extrapolated_image_id)
```